# when i add new blog error occurs in magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, blog

It displays below error when I add a new blog. 
I don't understand why it displays error. Previously add blog is working fine.

```
There has been an error processing your request
The file was not uploaded.
Error log record number: 452585771340
```

Comment: go to magento_root_folder/var/reports/ folder. and you can see 452585771340 file. Open that file and check the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: When adding new blog it's necessary to upload an image with the new blog.